# Connect Swift iOS client to Netty Server

Tags: java, swift, netty, nio

I am currently going about connecting an iOS application written in swift to my Java server using Netty.io. I was wondering if this is possible? And if so, is there any available resources with which I can learn? However, if it is not possible, I was wondering if any form of NIO / non blocking io can be used to connect the iOS with the Java server? I cannot change the language on which the server was written.
 Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Luckily, network interfaces don't speak swift or java. Neither do they care whether your process blocks while sending data or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think iOS application sends/receives regular bytes as any other application. So you can connect from iOS to Java (or any other) server, that supports your protocol. With Netty you can develop ant http/binary protocol you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. To you Netty server you could connect any client that supports you server protocol. To do it I recommend you this library [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket)

**For example:**

```
var client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr: "www.apple.com", port: 80)
var (success,errmsg)=client.connect(timeout: 1)
if success{
    var (success,errmsg)=client.send(str:"GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" )
    if success{
        var data=client.read(1024*10)
        if let d=data{
            if let str=String.stringWithBytes(d, length: d.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                println(str)
            }
        }
    }else{
        println(errmsg)
    }
}else{
    println(errmsg)
}
```

Hope it helps.